# Override Dependency Injection per request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two Net Core API Controllers: `RealController` and `MockController`, I want to inject differents services in the application based on which controller accept the request.

Example ,  if the request was accepted by the `RealController` I want to inject the `RealSharedService` (scoped) in all classes that it's needed, but if the request was accepted by `MockController` I want to inject the `MockSharedService` instead.

```
public class RealController : ControllerBase
{
    public RealController(...)
    {
        //I could do somethig here to change the ISharedService intance to RealSharedService
    }
}

public class MockController : ControllerBase
{
    public MockController(...)
    {
        //I could do somethig here to change the ISharedService intance to MockSharedService
    }
}

public class Service1
{
    public Service1(ISharedService sharedService)
    {
        //The ISharedService instance must be RealSharedService or MockSharedService based on
        // the request, if it was accepted by RealController or MockController
    }
}

public class RealSharedService : ISharedService
{
    ....
}
public class MockSharedService : ISharedService
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: `Service1` doesn't have an interface? How are you injecting it? And what's being injected in to the controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use HttpContextAccessor to conditionally resolve your service:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

services.AddScoped<ISharedService>(sp => {
   var httpContext = sp.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext;
   Endpoint endpoint = httpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint;
   if (endpoint.DisplayName.Contains("MockController"))
   {
      return new MockService();
   }
   else
   {
      return new RealService();
   }
});
```